# Is there DevExtreme support ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, devextreme

I used DevExtreme v22.3 but it doesn't support for ASP.NET Core 6 MVC. I used it good but it not working in some case (DataGrid, Popup, ...).

Can I have some advice for it?

Comment: Why don't you ask the official DevExpress Support ? They are the ones who would know the best if and how they support ASP.NET Core 6

Comment: Their latest release is just 22.2, so I wonder how come you are on 22.3. Besides, as one of the mainstream vendors DevExpress supports .NET 6 perfectly, so if you claim you hit issues, share a sample project somewhere to prove that.